# Passing Array as Argument to a Method

Tags: arrays, oop, methods, arguments, pass-by-reference

When we pass an array as argument to a method, the address of the first element is passed. Then, how the called method understand the number of elements in the received array?

Answer (score 0):

Usually passed 'arguments array' may has ability to return his own length, something like:

```
def foo(args)
   args_count = args.length #or args.size, args.count, depends on lang.
   ....
end
```